# How to make botcity generate the command correctly?

Tags: python, automation, bots

I'm using [BotCity](https://github.com/botcity-dev/botcity-framework-core-python) for automation but the system doesn't work.

After listing the image and indicating the action on the UI tab, BotCity does not create the code on the 'CODE' tab, how can I solve this problem?

```
from botcity.core import DesktopBot
from botcity.maestro import *


class Bot(DesktopBot):
def action(self, execution=None):

self.browse("https://www.facebook.com/groups/xxxxxx")

#in this field, the code should be created after the image is selected, but that doesn't happen, even if I leave the course selected in this line
  
    
def not_found(self, label):
print(f"Element not found: {label}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
Bot.main()
```

Comment: What's your Operating System? In case you're using Windows, try to run BotCity Studio as Administrator.

Comment: Hello,

I got this guidance on the BotCity forum and it was the solution to my problem, thanks.